# How to customize OpenMRS

Tags: openmrs

I have an OpenMRS installation. I installed it on my local system. I have not been able to find an appropriate module or way to customize it. Let's say change the logo and default color.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I'll assume you're referring to the latest OpenMRS 2 product rather than the older/simpler Platform product.

The style guide at http://demo.openmrs.org/openmrs/uicommons/styleGuide.page#override suggests adding a file called customVariables.scss with the colors, etc., you wish to override.

For the older Platform product, a quick Google search shows there is a "Custom Branding Module" at https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Custom+Branding+Module that looks like it might do what you want.

OpenMRS is not really a consumer product and has a relatively small number of users, so you probably won't get many answers here on SO. You'll probably be more successful if you use the project's Q&A site or forums if you don't get any more detailed answers.

Good luck!